# Setting Webpacker module options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dropzone.js, webpacker

I am a bit over my head - I have installed a few Webpacker modules in my Rails app - for example Dropzone:

```
require('dropzone')
```

I and it works - I have it on a page which I would like to specify the options:

https://www.dropzonejs.com/#configuration-options

like this for example:

```
Dropzone.options.newUpload = {
  paramName: 'upload[file]',
  maxFilesize: 100
}
```

I have tried adding this in several places including directly before the dropzone form in the view in a  tag.  No matter what the console throws errors (mostly 'Dropzone undefined' type errors).

I am guessing I am just not setting this correctly.  Any tips / suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using *modules* you should explicitly *import* from them

```js
import Dropzone from 'dropzone'

Dropzone.options.newUpload = {
  paramName: 'upload[file]',
  maxFilesize: 100
}
```

Repeat this import in every *your module* that's using `Dropzone` because these names don't fall into *global* scope.

Comment: Perfect - that did the trick.  I have another one like this that was driving me crazy (DataTables).  I suspect it's the same fix there.